# Handling background task with flask in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, flask

I have a service built with Flask which receives API requests and queues tasks (to the DB) and picks them up from the queue (on a schedule) and runs them in the background with multiprocessing.

The service runs in kubernetes and it works great however I have a route in Flask that should stop a task and this is where the trouble starts..

If I have 2 services running one of which is executing a task in the background and I want to stop it I send the request to the "/stop/taskid" route but it may (through the gateway) end up at the second service which does not run the task in question so it will not be able to stop it.

My question is what is the best way to handle this? I dont have any experience with kubernetes and this is my first time using it so if anyone could point me in the right direction on how this is usually handled it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if a job queueing system like Celery might work better for this.  As you note, if you have two replicas, in your setup you effectively have two job queues and API calls on one can't effect the other.

Comment: I already have a task queue and i don't see how that would change anything. I'm not talking about canceling a queued task. If one replica picks up the job from the queue and runs it and you want to stop the task that's already running having a queue wouldn't help since the task is already running and only the replica which is running the task is able to stop it.

Comment: Celery [documents an API to cancel a task](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/faq.html#can-i-cancel-the-execution-of-a-task) but as you say I don't know if that can interrupt a task that's already started.  I think you've identified the core problem: the "stop" request might be received by a replica that's not the one doing the task, and it needs to forward on that request to the right place in a way that the worker will pick that up.  That's not a concern Kubernetes handles on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get around this issue is to have a control instance and worker instance or if, as it is in my case, every instance is its own control, you can create a new queue for task actions.

The action to stop a task no longer tries to stop the task but adds the stop task action to the queue with the task id. Each instance then has a scheduled job to check this queue for the stop action and if it finds one it checks if the task id in question is owned by the instance. If yes then terminate the task and if no just ignore the action.